# Can anyone explain me the steps to setup version control system in Linux

Tags: version-control, linux

I am trying a lot and i am not bale to get how this version control work in my scenario

I have the VPS server where i host php sites. Users have home directories in /home/users.

Currently users edit files via FTP and i have no control what they do. I want to setup version control system on VPS i don't know hoe to start . I mean

I will explain what i want , i may be wrong but please correct me.

1. How can i install VCS on my VPS server so that all directories in /home/users are version controlled. I don't know if its possible or not. I want that final saving place or repo should be `/home/user/public_html` so that when user commit then my live site should change. Now i don't know if VCS works that way or not.
2. Now how will my client computers connect that VCS server
3. Is it possible to have version control for one user i mean `/home/user1/public_html` and not for others
4. Now users will still have FTP details , can't they change files via FTP even if i use VCS

Please clear my doubts , i really want to learn VCS systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the workflow is that you have a **repository** with all the revisions and changes. This uses a special format, there is no point in directly accessing these files. The repo is typically accessed thru WebDAV interface (running as an apache module), or running a standalone server (with it's own protocol).

Users **commit** their changes to the repo, then can **export** the latest revision (or one of their choice) to their publicly accessible *public_html* directory. This involves them interacting with the VCS and knowing (and caring) about it.

A simpler setup can be that the *public_html* contains a **working copy** and they interact with it thru conventional FTP. (You have to make sure that the VCS's files for example the `.svn` folders can not be accessed by the general public). This way you can expose the VCS functions (basically commit and rollback) to your users thru a web interface (you write a small PHP script that does the **commit** and **update** for your them).

**Incremental backups: a completely different story**

As I understood you probably need something more like incremental backups, for example **rsync**. Each time a user closes an FTP connection you can initialize an rsync backup. It has flexible options, you can have all the changes for the last X days, or last X FTP sessions, so the user could roll back after an accidental upload. (It can be used with a remote or local storage for backups).

Comment: Only *subversion* repo is accessed through WebDAV, so it's far from "typically". Typically it is accessed with restricted ssh (all VCS's support that method).

Comment: Of course anything can be done thru SSH, WebDAV just made more sense to me, thought it was more widely used.

Answer (score 3):

- Yes, it should be feasible. Expect to be storing some extra data as the whole history will be stored plus separate copy of the current version for the stored.
- You have to decide which version control system you want to use. The most common options are:

  - Subversion
  - Git
  - Mercurial
  - Bazaar

  If you or your users already have experience with one, than it's probably best choice.

  You want to:

  1. Install the version control system of choice and create a post-commit hook to check out each version into the target directories.
  2. Clients will commit into the respository. All the systems support access through restricted ssh (users log in using public key and the key is set in .ssh/authorized_keys to only allow one particular command). Some also have HTTP(s)-based method (special Apache module for Subversion, CGI script for Mercurial, Bazaar and Git).
  3. Yes; the hook script will check out what you tell it to. You can implement it to checkout for all users, listed users, users in a group, whatever you need.
  4. Turn the FTP server off.

Comment: Git does have an HTTP transport, see [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html)

Comment: @Hasturkun: It long didn't have one (it did have a dumb one, but that didn't support pushing), but you are right, it now has one.

Answer (score 0):

1. VCS (Version Control System) is just a class of software: You need to select one before you can implement it. In your case you probably want subversion, or one of the DVCS (Distributed Version control system) (git or mercurial).
2. It sounds like what you want is some kind of automated deployment system for your websites,  which is certainly possible.
3. Disabling ftp is easy: simply stop the ftp server from running: ftp is insecure and the servers are often dangerous themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how [Branchable](http://www.branchable.com/) works. They have specific web framework (ikiwiki), but the underlying principle of keeping the web sites in version control (git) is the same and all the software they use is open-source including the scripts that bind it all together, so you can look how it works.